# Apache mod_rewrite - rewrite doesn't occur at all

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, httpd.conf

I have an Apache 2.2 running on a windows machine.

I am trying to add some URL rewrite directives, and begun with the simplest sanity - rewrite every URL to *http://www.facebook.com* .

At **httpd.conf**, I've added the following:

> LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

and later in the file, the following:

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.facebook.com [R]

Redirection doesn't take place at all: **when I access existing files, I get them. When I access non-existing addresses, I get the server's 404 page**.

I attempted more complex rewrites, with the same result.

What might be the problem? Are there any log files I should check for hints regarding the redirection failure? Thanks!

Comment: The '#' is a comment character.  So you haven't done anything.

Comment: My bad - question refers to non-commented directives, of course.

Comment: Where exactly are you putting the directive? Is it inside a `VirtualHost` block?

Comment: Add a RewriteLog and a RewriteLogLevel directive and then look at the log info

Comment: Pekka - the rewrite directives are not within a VirtualHost. I tried both to put it outside any blocks (i.e. the final lines of the file) and within a directory block.  (<Directory "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\main">... </directory>)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `AllowOveride All` in your `VirtualHost` section

```
<Directory /path/to/your/www/>
    AllowOveride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: "AllowOveride All" has nothing to do with his issue. In fact, "AllowOveride None" is Apache's suggested default as the former allows everything, including .htaccess files, thus slowing down the web server (since Apache will look for for .htaccess files even if they don't exist with AllowOveride All).  Surprised this got upvoted...

Comment: @virtualeyes You're surely never configure .htaccess and the read apache docs, Surprised with this kind of comment.

Comment: indeed, I don't use .htacess files as they are a performance hit. If you read Apache performance docs you would avoid them as well: "http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/perf-tuning.html" (see section on AllowOveride). Further, you would not suggest that others use "AllowOveride All" when their problem has NOTHING to do with that ;-) Basically you are in fact creating a problem for users rather than helping solve the problem at hand...

Answer (score 0):

you have to put your rewrite rules within a virtual hosts block

```
<VirtualHost lan-ip:80>

ServerName mysite.com
ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com
DocumentRoot /path/to/site

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.facebook.com [R]

</VirtualHost>
```

where lan-ip could be localhost, or more likely, a dedicated ip to serve mysite.com. For local devel you can alias your NIC as say, 192.168.1.101, and modify /etc/hosts (on Linux), like so:

> 192.168.1.101 mysite.com

Then in your browser you can go to mysite.com and test against local test instance.